# android ListActivity not working with custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, listactivity, baseadapter

I am having trouble with what appears to be a simple use of a ListActivity with a custom adapter.  Here is the adapter code:

```
public class CustomRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomRowAdapter ( Context context )
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem( int position )
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId( int position )
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        LinearLayout rowLayout;

        if( convertView == null )
        {
            rowLayout = ( LinearLayout )LayoutInflater.from( mContext ).inflate( R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false );
        }
        else
        {
            rowLayout = ( LinearLayout )convertView;
        }

        return rowLayout;
    }
}
```

and here's the activity:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        setContentView( R.layout.list_layout );
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        CustomRowAdapter rowAdapter = new CustomRowAdapter( this );
        setListAdapter( rowAdapter );
    }
}
```

list_item_layout is just a LinearLayout with a single TextView in it, so I would expect to see 6 identical items in my list, but the list is empty.  I've stepped through CustomRowAdapter.getView() and it is being called with positions 0 through 5.  I must be missing something simple.  Why is the list appearing empty?

EDIT: The ListView has children in hierarchyviewer, so it looks like I may have an issue somewhere in my layouts.  Here's the layout containing the ListView:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="*" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:minWidth="65dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/back_button" android:text="@string/back"></Button>
            <TextView android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="16sp" android:text="@string/general_information"></TextView>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" android:minWidth="65dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/next_button" android:text="@string/next"></Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ListView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the layout for the list items:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I just pasted your code into a project and it works fine. I used the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 layout instead, but it worked. Are you sure the list is actually empty? Try putting something in R.layout.list_layout that is actually visible? A dummy TextView perhaps?

Comment: @StevePrentice I already have a dummy TextView in R.layout.list_layout.  That's how I know it's empty.  By "empty", I mean no entries visually appear in it.  If i step through getView() in the debugger, it is called with positions 0 through 5, so it seems like it should be working.  This might drive me crazy.

Comment: Perhaps your textview is the same color as the background? I.e. black on black or white on white? The only reason I ask is because I pretty much copy/pasted your code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Also, you can connect via hierachyviewer and see what views are actually children of your ListView. If your ListView has children, then your issue is with your layout and not your adapter.

Comment: @StevePrentice Sorry, I mean I have a dummy TextView in list_item_layout.  list_layout contains a few buttons and then the ListView that should be populated with 6 entries (each containing the dummy TextView).  I can see the buttons, but that ListView appears empty.

Comment: I posted them above.  The ListView does have children in hierarchyviewer (not 6 though, only 3 for some reason?), so maybe my issue is with my layouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `android:orientation="vertical"` to your top id/linearLayout1 (not the row).

On your row, you might want to add `android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` as well. That will keep your rows from getting too short.

Comment: Sigh...I knew it had to be something small and simple.  The top level LinearLayout being horizontal was of course the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting anything in your getView method. Check Efficient Adapter here is [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)

Comment: That does not appear to be my issue.  I was originally setting the text for the TextView in list_item_layout using TextView.setText(), and it still didn't show anything.  I removed that to make the example shorter, but I would still expect the code I posted above to result in a list containing 6 entries, all containing the default text from the TextView.